# Model generated by AWS autopilot

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, autopilot

After AWS Autopilot creates a model, How to use that model to the training data set offline?

How to use that .tar.gz model file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .tar.gz file is a model artifact

To create a model, you combine the algorithm container and the model artifact

You can do so in the Console, under Inference > Models > Create Model

What do you mean by "How to use that model to the training data set offline?"

If you mean, "run a batch transformation", then once you create a model, you can select the model in the console, then click 'Create batch transform job'

If you want to do it locally, then you can use the SageMaker Python SDK in [Local Mode](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#local-mode) and run the transform on your local computer (requires Docker)

Comment: I believe what he is asking is this , He's using ( example : DATASET A) to create a model using AWS autopilot and now he has another dataset (example : DATASET B) locally on his system and he wants to run that model (which is created by Dataset A) to Dataset B and get the results. That's what i understood.

Comment: Yes , Thankyou Neil for the solution and Haseeb for the further clarifications.